Wordpress redirect in CF7 to any API plugin
I have CF7 form and CF7 To Any Api plugin. I need to do a redirect to site, which I got in API response.
I found a file, where is called API. and there is something like:
if($input_type == "json"){
                if(!isset($header_request) && $header_request === ''){
                    $args['headers']['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';
                }
                $json = self::Cf7_To_Any_Api_parse_json($data);
            
                if(is_wp_error($json)){
                    return $json;
                }  
                else{
                    $args['body'] = $json;
                }
            }
            $result = wp_remote_post($url, $args);
            $result_body = wp_remote_retrieve_body($result);
            if(!empty($result_body)){
                $result = $result_body;
            }
            self::Cf7_To_Any_Api_save_response_in_log($post_id, $form_id, $result, $posted_data);

I added there:
$array = json_decode($result, true);
            $url = $array['url'];
            $fixed_url = str_replace("\\", "", $url);
            header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
            wp_redirect($fixed_url);
            exit();

But after send the form, there's error:
has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
I tried to change Access-Control-Allow-Origin * in .htaccess but with no success.
May I do this wp_redirect inside plugin?
